# Pandas: Custom group-by function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am looking for a custom group-by function that is going to group the rows in a way such that:

- If there is any number and 0 it will add the number.
- If there are two numbers (they will be the same all the time) then it will add the number.
- If there is a NaN and a NaN it will add a NaN.
- If there is a number and a NaN it will add the number.

An example to make things more clear:

```
start_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5],
                         "foo": [4, 4, np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 9, 9, 7],
                         "bar": [np.nan, np.nan, 0, 4, 0, 1, 6, 6, 0, 4]})

    id  foo  bar
0   1   4.0  NaN
1   1   4.0  NaN
2   2   NaN  0.0
3   2   7.0  4.0
4   3   NaN  0.0
5   3   NaN  1.0
6   4   0.0  6.0
7   4   9.0  6.0
8   4   9.0  0.0
9   5   7.0  4.0
```

After the custom group-by by `id`:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5], "foo": [4, 7, np.nan, 9, 7], "bar": [np.nan, 4, 1, 6, 4]})


    id  foo  bar
0   1   4.0  NaN
1   2   7.0  4.0
2   3   NaN  1.0
3   4   9.0  6.0
4   5   7.0  4.0
```

One solution that I am aware of is:

```
start_df.groupby("id").max().reset_index()
```

But it is too slow for my case since the data-frame that I am dealing with is huge. On the other hand, I am not able to cover the edge case where both of the elements are numbers with this solution:

```
start_df.groupby("id").sum(min_count=1).reset_index()
```

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Is it always sorted? You could just take the `tail` if so.

Comment: There is not only one column. This should be applicable for multiple columns. That is why max is too slow for me. I have more than 1M rows and 455 columns.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that you are doing this operation for multiple columns. However, if it's sorted, taking the tail should still work across multiple columns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "sorted"?

Comment: It seems all your values in `'val1'` column are sorted within each `id`. That is, for `'id' == 2`, you have `NaN` then `7.0`. Same for `'id' == 4`, `0.0` then `9.0`.

Comment: @busybear No, they won't be sorted. And I updated my example to be more specific.

Comment: Are the numbers always going to be integers?

Comment: @RobS Numerical. Integers and floats.

Comment: Dang. You could have used a bitwise OR if they were integers and handled the NaN with a try - except block.

Comment: @RobS Can you post an answer? What you are saying makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Unfortunately a bitwise OR won't work for you as you have floats.

Comment: two questions, you always have 2 rows per id? and only positive values or nan in your dataframe?

Comment: @Ben.T only positive values yes but the number of rows can vary from 1 row per id to mutiple rows per id.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not what you would have thought, but this should work

```
start_df.groupby('id').max()
```

Use `reset_index` if you want to bring 'id' back into the columns.

Comment: I posted that as a comment on another answer but I see that it is deleted now. However, this is too slow for my case. On the other hand, the problem with `start_df.groupby('id').sum(min_count=1).reset_index()`, is the case when there are two numbers (it is the same number as mentioned), and it should take one of them.

Comment: @gorjan Would you mind editing that into your question instead?

Comment: @ayhan Editted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking that fits ideal.

I have added the below another approach, Specifying `as_index=False` in groupby keeps the original index using [groupby.GroupBy.nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)

```
>>> start_df.groupby('id',  as_index=False).nth(1)
   id  foo  bar
1   1  4.0  NaN
3   2  7.0  4.0
5   3  NaN  1.0
7   4  9.0  6.0
```

OR

```
>>> start_df.groupby(['id'], sort=False).max().reset_index()
   id  foo  bar
0   1  4.0  NaN
1   2  7.0  4.0
2   3  NaN  1.0
3   4  9.0  6.0
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I am aware of that solution. Searching for the max element is an overkill for my case and thus too slow.

Answer (score 0):

here is another approach not with `groupby` but I can't tell if it is more efficient. The idea is to have the same number of rows for each id to be able to `reshape` the data and use `np.nanmax` over an axis. To do so, you can generate a dataframe with the missing values as nan.

```
#create the count of each id
s = start_df.id.value_counts()
nb_max = s.max()
#ceate the dataframe with nan
df_nan = pd.DataFrame({col: np.nan if col != 'id' 
                                   else [ids for ids, val in zip(s.index,nb_max-s.values) 
                                             for _ in range(val)] 
                       for col in start_df.columns })
#get the result
result_df = pd.DataFrame( np.nanmax( pd.concat([start_df, df_nan])[start_df.columns]
                                       .sort_values('id').values
                                       .reshape((-1,start_df.shape[1],nb_max)), 
                                     axis=1), 
                          columns = start_df.columns)
```

Note: you get a warning saying some slice are only `nan`, but it works, there is probably a way to silent this warning.